# Search JSON objects from URL -php

Tags: php, json

I have a url that returns:

```
[{"account":"123","address":"abc","category":"receive","amount":12,"confirmations":10,"tx":"6f8fa99a88c266ce403e0108f926adc02288f89be30adc298485961ac332a314"},
{"account":"123","address":"def","category":"send","amount":-5,"fee":-0.01,"confirmations":8,"tx":"6f8fa99a88c266ce403e0108f926adc02288f89be30adc298485961ac332a314"},
{"account":"123","address":"ghi","category":"receive","amount":23.59,"confirmations":5,"tx":"8b20ed5bf4a4d299bad42fd49b8aabf6456366b235288f34f79d9f2321cd11c9"}]
```

*I've tried various options found here at SO, but only been able to display all objects/values or using the code below to display a value. But unable to search all objects and only retrieve data from one particular object.*

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://...');
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

echo $json_a[0][txid];
```

All objects have some values that are exactly the same. I want to cycle through all objects for a particular 'address' and then if found, display 'amount, confirmations, tx' values.

How would I retrieve and use in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
foreach ( $array as $k=>$item ) {
    if ( $item['address']=='def' ) {
        /* Display other values for this record */
        echo 'Amount: ' . $item['amount'];
        /* etc. */
    };
};
```